# Functions or Classes as controller

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

When I display my controller (class) in console, I see that all dependencies are visible and all the dependencies of my dependencies are visible by the scope ...

[image]

But I know that everthing should be private if I use functions.

My question is : What is the best way to create controllers in angularjs (1.6) and What is the difference between classes (ES6) and functions.

Comment: Are you transpiling your ES6 to regular JS? Then there is no public/private destinction at runtime, only at compile-time.

Comment: Yes, can you post a reference for that ?

Comment: Not really, sorry. It's hard to find a reference for something that doesn't exist. Maybe you just need to look up how your TypeScript transpiler actually work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following pattern to keep those dependencies private and not have to assign them all to controller object.

```
function yourControllerFactory(yourDep1, yourDep2, ...) {
  class YourController {
    constructor() {
       // no longer have to assign every dependency to this object
    }
    ...
    doSomething() {
      yourDep1.doSomethingWithDep();
    }
  }
  return new YourController();
}

module('your-module').controller('yourController', yourControllerFactory);
```

This way, instances of `YourController` will NOT have access to your injected dependencies. This way is similar to how controllers were defined in the past.

Comment: No, don't do that. That creates a whole new class for every single instance.

Comment: Oh damn, you're right. I guess this is ok for controllers that are only used once.